# ERROR ITMS-90022 Missing Required Icon File

Tags: xamarin, icons, app-store-connect, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I was hoping someone could help me with an issue. I was attempting to upload my app to the App Store when suddenly I received an error message stating that I had a missing icon file. The error was:

> ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not
>   contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120'
>   pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

I haven't modified any of my icons but I did notice that when I updated the info.plist file to change the Build Number I noticed that the file had additional settings for "Car Play" and a few other devices which I hadn't specified any images for.

My plist.info file references an Asset Catalog and I have icons for IOS 7-9 specified. Im not sure what Ive done wrong.

Ive built my icons using the website https://makeappicon.com/ and Ive uploaded two previous versions of my app to the app store already without any issues. This is the first time this has happened.

Ive update XCode to v7.2, also updated the OS and applied all updates to Xamarin Studio.

Ive seen a few other people on the forums with this problem and they suggest changing the plist.info file to include the following:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
  <array>
    <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-76.png</string>
    <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>    
  </array>
```

This still doesn't work and the verification process fails. Furthermore, I don't think I should have to do this if my plist.info is referencing the asset catalog.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thank you
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unsatisfying as it is, I was able to resolve the same issue with my default issue resolution steps I have.

1. Updating Xcode (to v7.2.1 in this case)
2. Launch Xcode to install extras
3. Updating Xamarin (Xamarin.iOS to v9.4.1.25 in this case; Xamarin Studio stayed at v5.10.2)
4. Restarting machine
5. Clean the project ([obliterating the output first probably doesn't hurt](https://github.com/Redth/XamarinStudio.RedthsAddin))
6. Archiving again

I had this ITMS-90022 and two ITMS-90023 errors that both went away after that.