# XAMARIN IOS: Cannot submit to iTunes "Missing required icon file"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xcode9

Since upgrading to xcode 9.0 i can no longer submit my xamarin apps to itunes connect. I get this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
```

Which suggests I dont have either an app icon for 60@x2x or 40@3x, I can definitely see i have both in my asset catalogue! ive tried creating the asset catalogues in both xamarin studio and xcode but neither seem to work. My info.plist definitely also has the asset catalogue selected for the app icon. I can see some people needing a pod update to fix the issue in xcode 9 but being a xamarin app this isnt much good to me. Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142956/error-itms-90022-missing-required-icon-file maybe helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a bug with xamarin and xcode 9. Luckily im using microsoft mobile center for CI of my apps so i was able to configure the build to use xcode 8.3 to generate the ipa for now until xamarin release a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the SAME bug than you and tried everything (deleting all xcassets and icons and redo it all. Until I found that post: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104004/missing-app-icon-after-updating-to-ios-11-sdk

To summarize, the project I worked on had an another project linked to it with an xcassets catalog in it. I don't know if it's Xcode or Xamarin related, but it seems that at archive time, the secondary xcassets would mess something up on top of you primary project's xcassets that makes iTunes Connect not recognize the app icons.

The solutions are either of these:

- Move every secondary project's xcassets of your workspace into your primary project. (aside your xcassets containing your app icons, or merge them all in one)
- If that's not possible, remove the secondary project's xcassets and just the images it contained the old style way by adding them with the right name and @2-3x indicator.

If these solutions are not possible because you are using a cocoapod that includes an xcassets, I suggest making a pull request to the repo or entering an issue.

Comment: I had the same issue again later down the line and found that the image file itself was the problem. If you do 'get info' on the image file and check that 'alpa channel' is false and that 'color space' is RGB.